# Result of pgmathsetmacro is lost in loop iterations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

Consider the following code.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{0}

\foreach \k in {1,2,...,10}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{\k+\sumk}
  \directlua {print(\k,\sumk)}
}

\end{document}
```

In this simple example, I want to sum recursively from 1 to 10. This is just done to reproduce my problem: accessing a variable which is set within the loop in next loop iteration, and possibly accessing it also after the loop ended.

My expected output would be (in the log, written with lua `print`)

```
1   1.0
2   3.0
3   6.0
4   10.0
5   15.0
6   21.0
7   28.0
8   36.0
9   45.0
10  55.0
```

However, it is

```
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   6.0
7   7.0
8   8.0
9   9.0
10  10.0
```

Can a macro defined within the loop be reused later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 

\begin{document}

\def\sumk{0}
\def\finsumk{0}
\noindent\foreach \k in {1,2,...,10}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{\k+\finsumk}%
  \xdef\finsumk{\sumk}%
  %\directlua {print(\k,\sumk)}
  \k, \finsumk\\
}

\end{document}
```

PS: Add the lua code instead of my simple `LaTeX` way to print.

Output: Your desired output.

Reason of your failure: Try to change my `\xdef` to `\def` and you will realize that it doesn't work because been lost (gets 0) in every iteration. This is because `\sumk` is a value that expands for one usage inside the code and `\xdef` first expands it  and then save it globally.

Comment: The explanation helps me to understand it, thanks! Tikz even has some built-in functionality, but your answer seems more general.

Comment: Thanks @Faekynn ... Happy TeXing.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Ti*k*Z/pgf offers a quite simple solution. 
For me, the standard behavior is completely unexpected.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{0}

\foreach \k [remember=\sumk as \sumk] in {1,2,...,10}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{\k+\sumk}
  \directlua {print(\k,\sumk)}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a common behavior of `\foreach` compared to e.g. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` provided by `pgfplots`. You can get more information about this behavior and some examples in [`pgf-tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual § 7 *Utilities* and [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual § 8.1 *Utility Commands*.
I think it is because `\foreach` introduces scopes, while `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` does not, so the `\sumk` variable is not expanded.

The following example produces the desired output

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{0}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,10}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumk}{#1+\sumk}
  \directlua {print(#1,\sumk)}
}

\end{document}
```